# Inner if else of Arduino code is not working properly

Tags: arduino

Project has used soil moisture sensor and ultra sonic sensor. Based on the moisture level, it will decide whether to watering or not. Also using the ultra sonic sensor, it will check the water level of the tank. If water level is not sufficient it will not start the motor.

```cpp
int val; //stores the value received from Soil moisture sensor.
const int trigPin = 9; //pin for ultra sonic out
const int echoPin = 10; //pin for ultra sonic in
float duration, distance; //stores the values received from ultra sonic sensor.

void setup() {
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT); //Set pin 13 as OUTPUT pin, to send signal to relay
  pinMode(8,INPUT); //Set pin 8 as input pin, to receive data from Soil moisture sensor.
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); //Set pin 9 as OUTPUT pin, to send signal from ultra sonic sensor
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); //Set pin 10 as input pin, to receive data from ultra sonic sensor.
  Serial.begin(9600); //start serial monitor
}

void loop() { 
  val = digitalRead(8); //Read data from soil moisture sensor  
  Serial.print("Moisture: "); //print
  Serial.println(val); //print
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //set ultra sonic sensor to low
  delayMicroseconds(2); //delay
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); //set ultra sonic sensor to high
  delayMicroseconds(10); //delay
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //set ultra sonic sensor to low
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); //get the duration
  distance = (duration*0.0343)/2; //calculate the distance
  Serial.print("Distance: "); //print
  Serial.println(distance); //print
  if(val == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(13,LOW); //if soil moisture sensor provides LOW value send LOW value to relay
  } else {
    if(distance < 20.00){
        digitalWrite(13,LOW); //if distance is lesser than the limit, send LOW value to relay
    } else {
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH); //if distance is greater than the limit, send HIGH value to relay
    }
  }
  delay(1000); //Wait for few second and then continue the loop.
}
```

The issue is, according to the soil moisture sensor it's working properly. But the inner if else for ultra sonic sensor is not working. Even though value is calculated for distance always the motor is on instead the level of the water. Also water level is greater than 20.00 the soil moisture sensor related if else is also not working.

Comment: Did you, or can you put print statements to verify the logic is not working?  Is is possible your relay is not connected to pin 13 (either by mistake or you have a hardware "open")?

Comment: no it's connected. when put the Serial print without the digitalWrites it's working properly

Comment: I am not sure I follow you,  are you saying that if you add the Serial.prints, inside the inner if/else statements, you get the messages you expect, but you just don't get the results on the output pin?  Or are you saying that adding the Serial.print statements confirm that the logic is not work as you expect?

Comment: I just removed all the digitalWrites and add static values for distance and val and check. Then the logic works properly. But when the actually running it with the sensors it's not working. Sensors are returning the values correctly though.

Comment: what I am saying is just add Serial.print statements in addition to the digital writes inside the if / else statements and see if you get the prints and just not the pins being driven or if you don't get any messages from the digital writes, ie the if/else logic is really not working

Comment: basically as it stands the only way you can tell if the logic is working is by observing the affects of the digital_writes,  so if you add the Serial.prints along with the digital_writes, you will know if it's just that the wrong branches of the if/else are not being triggered or if the digital_writes are not working